# Java script event handler not firing as expected

Tags: javascript, events, handler

i am getting this issue,   JavaScript event handler is getting called as expected when the handler is provided as inline function call, however it does not work as expected when calling another function in response to event. I am  not sure why it is behaving that way, it will be great if some one can explain. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Name: <input type="text" id="text1"> Hello World!
  <script>
  var i= 0;
 function myFun()
 {
    i++;
   console.log('got key up event  ' + i);
 }    
 var textElem = document.getElementById('text1');
 //below works as expected  ie. prints 'got key up event 1', 'got key up     
   event 2' .. on console
 //textElem.addEventListener('keyup', function () {i++; console.log('got   key up event ' + i);});

 //If we comment above call and use below - textElem.addEventListener...
 // it does not work as expected it only logs 'got key up event 1' on page load
// after that it (myFun) is not getting called even if i press key on text box. 
 //textElem.addEventListener('keyup', myFun() );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
textElem.addEventListener('keyup', myFun );
```

i.e. `myFun` without `()`

`addEventListener` is expecting a function as a second parameter. If you pass `myFun()` the browser evaluates the function (and here you got `got key up event 1`), but the function returns nothing, so the actual event listener is not added.

When you pass `myFun`, the actual function is added as event listener.

Comment: Thank you very much it works (as we need to provide a delegate, and not to call the function itself) apologies for not noticing it myself.